# AndroidBitmap_lockPixels always failing

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

In my `jni` module I copy images to `bitmaps`, which were previously
passed from my java application.

I do this using `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels/AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels`.
Basically, it renders the image correctly, but there're strange
effects: sometimes the application gets stuck, or after some time
`AndroidBitmap_lockPixels` always returns -3

`(ANDROID_BITMAP_RESULT_ALLOCATION_FAILED)`. I guess this is because I
update these bitmaps not from the `GUI` thread, isn't it?

If so, what would be correct way to "post" this operation to the GUI

thread? Is it possible in `jni` ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am running into this as well. As OP said, it runs fine for "a while" but then AndroidBitmap_lockPixels starts returning -3. On some Androids, it can run for hours, updating at 10fps, but on others it starts doing this after only a few minutes. Any ideas?